# Expected value of weighted random variable

Tags: correlation, expected-value, weights

I have a statistic I'm investigating that depends on estimates from a correlation matrix. The statistic is:
$$
T = \sum_{i=1}^{m} d_{i} w_{i}
$$
where $d_{i}\sim Bern(\pi)$ and is independent of $w_{i}$ which is a weight that depends on the sample Pearson correlation matrix (and thus a bunch of pairwise sample Pearson correlation coefficients) between $m$ different variables. Formally:
$$
w_{i} = \left(\sum_{j=1}^{m}r_{i,j}^{2}\right)^{-1}
$$
where $r_{i,j}$ is the sample Pearson correlation between two different variables. So if you have a correlation matrix between $m$ variables, $w_{1}= (r_{11}^{2}+r_{12}^{2}+..+r_{1m}^{2})^{-1}$

I want the expected value and variance of this statistic. What I really care about is the parameter $\pi$, but the weighting helps me account for how much each of the $m$ variables is contributing to the total statistic.

Originally I proceeded as follows. Given a sample with $m$ variables:
$$
\begin{align}
E[T] = &\sum_{i=1}^{m} E[d_{i}w_{i}]\\
 = \pi&\sum_{i=1}^{m} E[w_{i}]\\
= \pi&\sum_{i=1}^{m} w_{i}
\end{align}
$$

That is I didn't take the expected value of $w_{i}$ since given the sample it is fixed depending on the correlation matrix and all I really care about is $\pi$ and the sum of the weights has an intuitive (if not formal)  definition as an estimate of the unique number of endpoints represented by the $m$ total endpoints.

Now that I've thought about it a little more, my question is, is that a valid thing to do? Or do I need to find the expected value of $w_{i}$? My confusion comes from the fact that given a sample $w_{i}$ is fixed and I'm not sure $w_{i}$ is estimating an actual population parameter.

If I do need to find the expected value of $w_{i}$ besides bounding it below using Jensen's inequality I'm not sure how I would proceed. And even if I can get the expected value it would be in terms of $\rho_{ij}$ which is unknown and not of main interest.

Comment: This doesn't help you much you've got to decide if you are estimating the $w_i$ or should assume they are fixed constants. if fixed constants, then the variance is probably derivable. if the $\hat{w}_i$ are estimates of the true $w_{i}$ and have a variance, then it will oviously be more difficult. Not assuming they are fixed would be analogous to classical linear regression, where we assume that the $\hat{\beta}$ are estimates of the true $\beta$ and we construct an estimate of them along with the variance of that estimate.

Comment: @mlofton thanks for the response. Can you think of a corresponding example where something is assumed to be fixed? In general are there advantages to one method besides assuming they are constant making it much easier to find the expected value and variance?

Comment: Hi: The $X_{i}$ in a classical regression model are often assumed to be fixed.  That's an obvious one but it still consistent in that, it's the $\beta$ estimates that have a variance and this variance is really due to the variation of the response, not the $X_{i}$. So, you need to decide where the variation is coming from and what terms in the statistic you are calculating are dependent on that variation.

Answer (score 1):

$$T = \sum_{i=1}^{m} d_{i} w_{i}$$ where $d_i∼Bern(π)$ and is independent of $w_i$.

1) when $w_i$ is constant:
$$E(T) = E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} d_{i} w_{i}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} E(d_{i} w_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} w_{i} E(d_{i}) = \pi\sum_{i=1}^{m} w_{i} $$
$$Var(T) = \pi(1-\pi)\sum_{i=1}^{m} w_{i}^2 $$

2)  when $w_i$ is random:

$$E(T) = E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} d_{i} w_{i}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} E(d_{i} w_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} E(w_{i}) E(d_{i}) = \pi\sum_{i=1}^{m} E(w_{i}) $$

$E(d_{i} w_{i}) = E(w_{i}) E(d_{i})$ is based on $d_i$ and $w_i$ are independent.

$$Var(T) = \pi(1-\pi)\sum_{i=1}^{m} E(w_{i}^2) + \pi^2Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} w_{i}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, these are the same results I was getting. Unfortunately the expected value of the weights is not trivial and I believe has to do with a non-central chi-square. I haven't tagged it as accepted since I was hoping to get more insight into which approach might be more appropriate (i.e. advantages/disadvantages of the two). Obviously I would prefer to treat them as constant for simplicty, but I don't know if that is making too much of an assumption for practical uses. I know these questions may not have a definite answer but I would appreciate your opinion.

Comment: In fact, two things I cannot understand in your question. 1) You addressed two times that you are interesting in  $\pi$. If so, why you need $w$? just observe/analyze $d$ is enough. 2) relationship between $d$ and $w$. It seems they come from two source (so they are independent). If $w$ comes from a trial and this trial will be repeated 5 years later, then $w$ will be changed , and $d$ is come from daily job, then treat $w$ as constant is totally reasonable. BTW, expectation and variance of $w, w^2$ and sum of $w$ are hard to get. Need to pay attention to their correlation.